# Efficient data structure for a record consisting of a tuple and its value

Tags: java

I want to store sort of a tuple and a value as an entry. I mean something like this

```
A B -> 1
A C -> 2
E F -> 3
C D -> 4
```

The first two values are always unique, in the sense A and B occur only once together. What would be an efficient data structure for the purpose, keeping in mind that I may need to fetch any of the three fields from an entry efficiently ?

If possible, please provide some relevant code !!

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Perhaps something with [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `Map` would work well. You need to have an object to represent the first two items. Make sure that the `hashCode` and `equals` methods are implemented correctly on your new class. Then you can use that class for the key.

```
Map<MyKeyClass, Integer> map = new HashMap<MyKeyClass, Integer>();
map.put(new MyKeyClass("A", "B"), 1);
map.put(new MyKeyClass("A", "C"), 2);
```

Comment: Agreed. And make the class for the map's key immutable if possible.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use a HashMap, for example:

```
public class Test {
    public void TestHashMap() {
        Map<Tuple<String,String>, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<Tuple<String,String>, Integer>();
        myMap.put(new Tuple<String,String>("A","B"), 1);
        myMap.put(new Tuple<String,String>("A","C"), 2);

        myMap.get(new Tuple<String,String>("A","C"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class MyData{
   public char name, fname;
    public int value;

public Foo(char name, char fname, int value){
    this.name = name;
    this.fname = fname;
}
}
```

Comment: Nothing keeps them unique. (Also missing the setting of 'value' in the constructor.